# How to refer back to public_html root file using include after going up one file directory out of public_html

Tags: php, security, include, root

Based on some exceptionally helpful tips, I am using the following code to include `PHP` files outside my root directory which looks similar to this:

```
define('WEB_ROOT', __DIR__);
define('APP_ROOT', dirname(__DIR__));
define('PHP_ROOT', APP_ROOT . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'application');


include(PHP_ROOT . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'bootstrap.php');
```

My question is this, lets say for example you include the code `bootstrap.php` as per what you have above.

What if that `PHP` file bootstrap then had its own line of code the included a file BACK in the public_html root folder.... how would one code that? I am having some difficulty doing this, my objective here is that I dont want to put actual literal directories in full in the code and I want to avoid file traversal attacks

Comment: If you don't want to use absolute paths, one way is to define a variable in the "outer" script that will be then used in the included "inner script".  For example: `$include_prefix = <something>;` in the outer script and `if(isset('include_prefix')){ include($include_prefix . "<something>"); }` in bootstrap.php.  I think absolute paths are you best approach, however, if security and reliability are of any serious concern.

Comment: Oh sorry I should clarify the trouble I believe I am having is that instead of simply being able to go include("thatfilebackinrootdirectory.php"); for example, and it working...its giving me an error saying there's no such file or directory, I am presuming because I've gone up one directory out of root its now not knowing how to refer back to a public_html php file from where it is?

Comment: You're right about why that error is appearing.  There are a number of solutions out there -- I'll go into more detail in an answer, one sec.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider this project structure:

```
/path/to/projectroot/index.php
                     header.php
                     include/inc.php
```

If index.php had

```
include('include/inc.php');
```

and inc.php had

```
include('header.php');
```

You'd get that error since the line in inc.php would be looking for

```
/path/to/projectroot/include/header.php  (doesn't exist)
```

not

```
/path/to/projectroot/header.php (does exist)
```

There are a few ways people resolve this.

**1: Absolute paths**

The first, and most straightforward is to use absolute paths.

If index.php had

```
include('include/inc.php');
```

and inc.php had

```
include('/path/to/projectroot/header.php');
```

This would work.

**2: Absolute paths with defines**

Similar to #1, if index.php had

```
define('PROJECT_ROOT', '/path/to/projectroot/');
include(PROJECT_ROOT.'include/inc.php');
```

and inc.php had

```
include(PROJECT_ROOT.'header.php');
```

This would work.

**Update:** As noted in the comments by [pichan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/365488/pichan), you could use one of the ["magic" constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) here in index.php, so:

index.php

```
define('PROJECT_ROOT', __DIR__.'/');
include(PROJECT_ROOT.'include/inc.php');
```

and inc.php

```
include(PROJECT_ROOT.'header.php');
```

Note we add a trailing slash to `__DIR__` here since:

> This directory name does not have a trailing slash unless it is the root directory.

**3: Include both and hide errors**

If inc.php had

```
@include('header.php');    # Try this directory
@include('../header.php'); # Try parent directory
```

This would work.[1]

**4: Assume current directory unless otherwise specified**

If index.php had

```
$rel_prefix_to_root = '../';
include('include/inc.php');
```

and inc.php had

```
if(!isset($rel_path_to_root)){ $rel_path_to_root = ''; }
include($rel_path_to_root . 'header.php');
```

This would work.

**My take on these methods**

1 and 2 are basically the same, but 2 is a little bit easier and more common for big projects since it allows you to make one constant definition and use it site-wide.  It also allows you to deploy the project on multiple servers (placed in multiple paths) and only requires changing one line project-wide, as opposed to one line in each file for option 1.

3 is terrible, don't do it.  Sometimes you'll see it, you might even see it in tutorials online.  Don't do it.

4 should probably be avoided in favor of 1 or 2.  But this approach might be necessary if you have some complex set of includes.

Some Notes:

[1] This is a terrible idea.  It works, but don't do it.

Comment: So @jedwards do you mean example 1 of the 4 methods is the least favored of all 4 solutions?

Comment: @Kalcoder: I would say that 3 is the least favored.  1 is commonly used in smaller projects and will work perfectly (provided the path is correct).  2 is a bit easier to maintain than 1, but they're functionally the same.

Comment: @jedwards I'd like to suggest an improvement for #2: Instead of hard-coded path you can do `define('PROJECT_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__)); //or just __DIR__` in index.php. I'm sure you knew this already but this should be preached more, especially since yours is the accepted answer :)

Answer (score -1):

To get the directory above public_html I use the following
$aboveRoot = explode('/public_html', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
define('ABOVE_THE_ROOT', $aboveRoot[0]);

Comment: I accept that this is a bad/poor answer. I was just wondering why?

Comment: Well I am always curious and have an open mind. I think everyone will benefit from an answer I guess. @George, what I'm doing this this...I im public_html, I go one up, I go into another folder, lets call this folder batman, I go into batman, I THEN want to include a file thats in public_html, so somehow, I need to go back into public_html without risking any security holes that will enable someone to file traverse or hack it in anyway

Comment: Actually also @George I think he might of been referring to example number 1 (of 4) that he was giving, saying that option 1 from his own post perhaps isnt the best of the 4 examples given, so please keep posting answers, sharing knowledge is good in any form :)